# How to open a terminal in bash script and continue running script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that will type out commands and enter them using xdotool. The only problem is that at the start of the script requires a terminal to be opened (by the script) and then to continue running the script. The script is going to be ran on Kali Linux so it has xfce4-terminal, xterm, bash etc

I tried simulating crtl alt t but it did not work

Explanation attempt #2:
My bash script simulates keyboard input and types commands to automate a task. The input would go into a terminal. I need to open a terminal at the stsrt of a script, when I do this anyway I can think of it makes the script pause until the terminal is closed. I need a way to open a terminal and continue running the original script without pausing, does this clarify?

Image of script src:
[image]

Comment: Hi, please [replace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/565284/edit) photo with just text, also clarify your question a bit more, currently it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: My bash script simulates keyboard input and types commands to automate a task. The input would go into a terminal. I need to open a terminal at the stsrt of a script, when I do this anyway I can think of it makes the script pause until the terminal is closed. I need a way to open a terminal and continue running the original script without pausing, does this clarify?

Comment: have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/46627/283843

Comment: Two bad descriptions does not make a good one. Please proofread and improve the question.

Comment: Why are you trying to automate typing commands? It it because you think this is a good way to run the commands?

Comment: To automate the task the script completes. It is going to dump wpa handshakes using bettercap. I can't do this using a normal script as bettercap needs to be running constantly to detect wireless acvess points and the sleep command would not be detected by bettercap, hence the poorly made hacky solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to open a `xfce4-terminal` and continue running your script you can just start the command in the background like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

xfce4-terminal &
sleep 5 # wait for terminal window to be ready

# continue with your script
xdotool type '...'
```

However, what I think you should **actually** be doing is to rethink your whole approach since it looks overly complicated to achive what you're propably after! (unless there re some special requirements you didn't mention yet)

If you simply want to execute the commands as a script, you can put them there directly:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

airmon-ng stop wlan1mon
# note:
# no sleep required since the commands are executed one after another,
# waiting for the previous one to finish
airmon-ng check kill

# ...
```

If you want the output of the script to be visible in a `xfce4-terminal` window you can just open one manually and start the script in it.

If you need to start the script automatically - e.g. on startup - but still want the output to be in a new window, start the script with `xfce4-terminal -e /path/to/your/script.sh`, see https://askubuntu.com/q/46627/283843 as mentioned by [αғsнιη](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/72456/%ce%b1%d2%93s%d0%bd%ce%b9%ce%b7).

If you need to enter input into other commands you may try to simply `echo` and pipe it to them:

```bsh
echo "events.stream off" | bettercap --iface wlan1mon
```

Or, depending on the command, find a more appropriate way to provide it with inputs or start it with the respective parameters, since the above may not work in all cases.
I.e., for `bettercap` you may use the [`-eval` Parameter](https://www.bettercap.org/usage/#eval-commands):

```bsh
bettercap --iface wlan1mon -eval 'events.stream off; wifi.recon on'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am a complete beginner to batch, first script I have ever written. As for the simpler, cleaner solution I don't think it's usable as this script runs on a pi and dumps handshakes every minute and if it were to use -E the sleep command wouldn't be recognized in bettercap and bettercap needs to be running constantly to detect wifi aps.

Comment: You're welcome!
If this answers your question, remember to mark it as accepted solution. If there is still something missing to solve your problem please update your question to include the remaining requirements - especially your whole script _as text_. One thing you might try is to run bettercap in background with `bettercap --iface wlan1mon &` so your script may continue to execute.